# How to implement Azure table storage to allow for Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, mocking, azure-table-storage

I am implementing unit tests for a Azure Table Storage based persistence component. The project has multiple Table Storage persistence components, so currently these implement an abstract `TableStorageBase` class to share common code between them.

Say we have a class `FooTableStorageComponent` under test, that retrieves a `Foo` from Table Storage, and if it has expired (i.e. the timestamp is older than 7 days), it creates a new `Foo`. I would like to create a Table Storage stub that always gives `FooTableStorageComponent` a dummy `Foo` older than 7 days. I would then like to create a unit test that checks that a new `Foo` is hence created. Unfortunately, due to the abstract `TableStorageBase` class, I can't fake connecting to Azure.

**How can I redesign this structure to make it unit testable? How should I go about unit testing my `FooTableStorageComponent`?**

**Abstract TableStorageBase class:**

```
public abstract class TableStorageBase
{
    private readonly string tableName;
    protected readonly CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
    protected TableRequestOptions DefaultTableRequestOptions { get; }
    protected OperationContext DefaultOperationContext { get; }
    public CloudTable Table
    {
        get
        {
            return storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(tableName);
        }
    }

    public TableStorageBase(
        string connectionString,
        string tableName,
        LocationMode consistency)
    {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        ServicePoint tableServicePoint = 
            ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(storageAccount.TableEndpoint);
        tableServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
        tableServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 500;
        DefaultTableRequestOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
        {
            PayloadFormat = TablePayloadFormat.JsonNoMetadata,
            MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), 3),
            LocationMode = consistency
        };

        DefaultOperationContext = new OperationContext();
        Table.CreateIfNotExists(DefaultTableRequestOptions, DefaultOperationContext);
    }
}
```

**Class under test:**

```
public class FooTableStorageComponent : TableStorageBase, IFooComponent
{
    private const string TableName = "foo";
    private const LocationMode ConsistencyMode = LocationMode.PrimaryOnly;

    public FooTableStorageComponent(string connectionString)
         : base(connectionString, TableName, ConsistencyMode)
    {
    }

    public GetFoo(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<FooTableEntity>(partitionKey, rowkey)
        var tableEntity = (await Table.ExecuteAsync(
            retrieveOperation, 
            DefaultTableRequestOptions, 
            DefaultOperationContext)).Result as FooTableEntity;
        if (tableEntity != null && tableEntity.Timestamp > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
        {
            return tableEntity.ToEntity();
        }
        else
        {
            var foo = CreateFoo(partitionKey, rowKey)
            var insertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(FooTableEntity.From(foo));
            await Table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
            return foo;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think unit testing the `FooTableStorageComponent` wont make much sense since the methods heavly rely on table operations and table entities. Its a simple repository without any business logic so an integration test would be more suitable since it depends on a sub system.

You would provide a fake implementation for a unit test that uses `IFooComponent`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. The example of business logic I'd want to test is the 7 day expiry on table entities. I don't want to test Table Storage itself. I was thinking maybe of separating the Table Storage I/O logic into some generic access class, or somehow intercepting the accessing of table storage in order to spoof it. Perhaps I must just accept that it's not unit testable.

Comment: You could write a service with a function that takes a timestamp, an object and a factory function and outsource the logic there. Then you would be able to test it but I realy think you don't have to.

Comment: Or perhaps just a public method within the repository component that covers that logic. Feels a bit contrived, but I think I'll go for that, thanks.